# I can't use volley library in my Android Project, Android Studio 3.1.3

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle

Good afternoon, I had a new problem in my android project, I don't know why but i can't implement a volley library in my project, i'm using Android Studio 3.1.3 API 26
I need a help.

[image]

Comment: project gradle inside check this  repositories {
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: gradle project sync failed. Basic functionality (e.g. editing, debugging) will not work properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your `gradle` to v `3.2.0`:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0'
```

And make sure you have added:

```
repositories {
        google() // should be always the first one
        jcenter { url "http://jcenter.bintray.com/" }
         maven {
            url "https://jitpack.io"
        }
}
```

In your root `build.gradle` repositories which is located in your project `root -> build.gradle`.

For better understanding:

[image]

Comment: Mohsen can you post a screenshot about how can I do that?

Comment: No need. Go to your root `build.gradle` which has classpaths and repositories. Just update the gradle version by replacing my suggested version. And add those repos to your repository too. I'll add a screenshot.

Comment: Anyways, it seems like you're using Android Studio v3.1.3. Better to updating to v3.2.

Comment: i'm still getting this : gradle project sync failed. Basic functionality (e.g. editing, debugging) will not work properly

Comment: thank you,  it seems like my internet was not working properly a few hours ago, and now it worked. I'm glad for your help.

Comment: Good to hear that. Well yeah that could cause the issue too. Let’s use the latest version ..